# MVC3 unit tests failed System.Security.VerificationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, razor

I faced with strange behavior of MVC3 RC.

I create default Internet application with unit tests and all unit tests were failed on my computer. All tests have error `"System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime."`. The error raises on controller creation action.
After that I run Windows XP Mode on my computer and repeated the same actions. All tests were successful.
My computer runs  Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

What is the cause of it?

Comment: added asp.net-mvc tag to broaden reader audience.

Comment: Did you try creating a new unit test project and doing `Assert.AreEqual(1,1)` just to see if you have a broader problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you touched the project at all? Check the references etc., some people have [reported this issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1672765.aspx/1/10) and it turned out to be 3rd party libraries [like TypeMock](http://forums.asp.net/t/1672765.aspx/2/10).